# Download file and encrypted file that can only view in my flutter application

Tags: flutter

I developed flutter app that can download file. But downloaded file (eg image file) can be viewed in Gallery. I want to develop downloaded file that can be viewed only in my flutter app. I used `flutter_downloader`.

please use this line code:--

String dir = (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path;

more details visit [more...](https://www.gadgetsteach.com/)

Comment: Probably you need to hot refresh the page.

Comment: How can I do for hot refresh page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flutter or any other framework manages stack for screen navigation,

So in flutter if you navigate to another screen, the old screen goes to the stack in memory, it does not dispose.

In your case

you can use `Navigator.pushReplacement` instead if `Navigator.push`.

With `Navigator.pushReplacement` flutter framework will remove Login Page from stack.

Or

If you don't want to remove your Login Page from your stack,
Just clear your `TextField` using controller before navigation.

Comment: Question is edited sir.